# How to close gnome terminal screen from program in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, process, gnome

I am writing server and client socket program .

The server manages connections between clients.

When client wants to chat with another I open new terminal screen using :

```
              char command[MAXBUFSIZE];
              strcpy(command,"gnome-terminal -e './client ");
              strcat(command,client.url);
              strcat(command," ");
              strcat(command,client.port);
              strcat(command," '");
              system(command);
```

Is there any way to know from this block the number of process which have this new terminal.

Because I want to try something like this:
When client wants to chat with another friend he tells the server and automatically the terminal with the last one close .

So I have to write here command which kill the process that open last terminal chat screen.

Comment: And that's why professionals don't use `system()` for this use case.

Comment: I am not  professional but I try to be.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec

Comment: It mean I have to call this block in child process?

Comment: Replacing the concatenation and `system()` call appropriately, yes.

Comment: So I want to open new terminal using different method

Comment: Does the terminal automatically close if `./client` exits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to know from this block the number of process which
>   have this new terminal.

No; replace it with:

```
    char command[MAXBUFSIZE];
    sprintf(command, "./client %s %s", client.url, client.port);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {   int status;
    case -1:    perror("fork");
                break;
    case 0:     execlp("gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal", "-e", command, NULL);
                perror("exec");
                exit(1);
    default:    // You may kill the new terminal process "pid", as you wish.
                // wait(&status); if you want to.
    }
```